# SSLEngine unwrap() javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: bad record MAC

Tags: java, ssl, nio, jsse, sslengine

This has been driving me crazy for a few days now. I created a client using java nio with ssl encryption using an SSLEngine. Handshake works fine, and I write a GET request to a website and it works fine (I get the header with 200 code). The problem is that when the website sends the packets back, on the second packet I get a BadPaddingException. Here is my read method:

```
    public void read(SelectionKey key,ByteBuffer readBuffer) throws IOException, BadPaddingException {

    SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

    ByteBuffer clientSSLData = ByteBuffer.allocate(getPacketBufferSize());
    System.out.println("Reading data. PacketBufferSize: "+(getPacketBufferSize()));
    int length = socketChannel.read(clientSSLData);

    System.out.println("read "+length+" bytes");
    if (length == -1){
        System.out.println("Length is -1 which means nothing was read from the channel  ");
        socketChannel.close();
        return;
    }
    clientSSLData.flip();
    readBuffer.clear();
    SSLEngineResult res = sslEngine.unwrap(clientSSLData, readBuffer);
    System.out.println(res.toString());
}
```

My get request is something simple like this: "GET \r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n"

Basically if its a small website like https://www.example.com, I have no problem receiving because it sends it in one read. But if I do something like https://www.google.com, I get the BadPaddingException. Any ideas? Thank you!

EDIT: Exception is...

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
>       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source)
>       at ssl.engine.impl.SecureIO.read(SecureIO.java:244)
>       at ssl.engine.impl.ChannelHandler.read(ChannelHandler.java:144)
>       at ssl.engine.impl.ChannelHandler.run(ChannelHandler.java:69)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: bad record MAC
>       at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.decrypt(Unknown Source)
>       ... 8 moreClosing down

Comment: Your GET request is invalid. It's missing a resource and an HTTP version. It won't be causing this problem but you should fix and retest anyway as a matter of course.

Comment: Thanks EJP, I forgot to mention that I used to have the http version before but still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing this wrong. When you need to get data you should:

1. Get from your app receiver buffer.
2. If that's empty, try `unwrap().`
3. If that gives you a buffer underflow, read the channel.

Similarly when you need to put data, you should:

4. Put to your app send buffer.
5. If that fills, `wrap().`
6. Write if that gives you a buffer overflow.

Or do all that when you need to flush.

Your primary interface should be with the engine, and only with the channel as a result of what the engine tells you about buffer underflows and overflows.

Similarly you must let the engine dictate the handshake (NEED_WRAP/NEED_UNWRAP) rather than try to dictate to it.

The `SSLEngine` is a very difficult thing to get right. Many have tried: few have succeeded. For one working success, that is the basis for a commercial product, see the `SSLEngineManager` class in the source code for my book *Fundamental Networking in Java*, Springer 2006, [here](http://dadaelectronics.com.au/FNJ/FundamentalNetworkingInJava.zip).

Comment: Thanks. Your advice really helped a lot along with the few examples out there on the web. It has taken me 3 days to implement this SSLEngine.

Comment: @EJP why do you say it doesn't support handshaking?